# Column name not recognised in CASE statement

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL and I can't get this syntax right.I have a table googleplaystore and column ratings where I have to remove last letter if it's 'k' or 'M'.

It's says: Invalid column name 'Size'
I also tried to write SELEFT Size FROM googlplaystore and then CASE statement but it's not working.

```
SELECT Size,
CASE
WHEN RIGHT(Size,1) = 'k' THEN SELECT SUBSTRING(Size,1,LEN(Size)-1) 
END
FROM googleplaystore
```

Comment: It seems like your table doesn't have a column `Size`. It would be easier for us to provide you with more help if you include more information about your specific problem like: what dbms is used and what columns does your table actually have. Please [edit] your question, tag appropriate dbms and add `CREATE TABLE` script of your table (as text!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.
remove second  `select`

```
SELECT Size,
CASE
WHEN RIGHT(Size,1) = 'k' THEN SUBSTRING(Size,1,LEN(Size)-1) 
END
FROM googleplaystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using replace, which will simplify your sql:

```
select size, replace(size,'k','') from googleplaystore
```

I suppose since the column name is size, there won't be any other k's than the one at the end.